# A thermodynamics problem with an interesting equilibrium condition

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, energy

Usually, when we analyze reactions, we assume that the reaction takes place at constant pressure or at constant volume. But there is no reason to assume this is generally the case, and so my friend posed the following question that has a different condition:

> $n=0.1$ mols of $\ce{SO3}$ are put into a container of volume $V_0 = 3\pu{L}$ at temperature $T=1100\pu{K},$ and reaches an equilibrium mixture with $\ce{SO2}$ and $\ce{O2}.$ The temperature is held constant at $T$ and the quantity $V - c\cdot P$ where $c = 20 \frac{\pu{L}}{\pu{bar}}$ is always constant during the reaction. Assume everything is ideal. Use any reference data as appropriate. What are the equilibrium concentrations of all compounds?

First, for the thermodynamic constants, it is not hard to find their values at 1100 K from the reference ones at 298 K simply by using   their relation with temperature and heat capacity. I get that $\Delta H = 95.6\pu{kJ}$ and $\Delta S = 99.3\pu{J/K}$ when one mol of $\ce{SO3}$ decomposes.

Ordinarily, in constant volume or constant pressure scenarios, we can find the equilibrium concentration simply from the equation $\Delta G = - RT \ln K$ or $\Delta A = - RT \ln K$ and then use known values of Gibbs/Helmholtz formation enthalpy to calculate the concentrations. But here, neither of these equations apply since neither volume nor pressure is constant.

From the condition of ideality it is not hard to derive a formula for the volume and pressure with respect to the extent of reaction $\xi:$
$$P_0 = n\cdot R\cdot\frac{T}{V_{0}}$$
$$V_1 = \frac{V_{0}-cP_{0}+\sqrt{\left(V_{0}-cP_{0}\right)^{2}+4RTcn\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\xi\right)}}{2}$$
$$P_1 = n\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\xi\right)\cdot R\cdot\frac{T}{V_{1}}$$

but I'm not sure how to proceed in this problem afterwards. One thought I had was to maximize total entropy, but this seems quite hard to set up.

Comment: From your initial conditions, you know that P1 = 3.049 bar, and thus that V – c P = –57.97 L (you said it was "always constant" during the reaction, which would apply to the start of the reaction as well).  Thus P, in bars, will always be (according to your constraint) 50 x (0.05797 + 0.001 V), where V is in liters.  But this reaction may not follow that constraint.  Do you know that it does?  If it does, that gives you a third equation to add to your equations for V1 and P1: V1 – c P1 = –57.97 L.  Thus you now have three (independent?) equations and three unknowns (V1, P1, and ).

Comment: @theorist The condition should be true all throughout the reaction, and I used that condition on V-cP to derive the formula for V1. It should be P0 = 3.049 bar rather than P1? So, we still only have two independent equations :/

Comment: Ah, yes, I meant P0 = 3.049 bar.   What was your friend's basis for coming up with V – c P = –57.97 L?  What was the idea behind this particular constraint?  And your friend wouldn't happen to be a professor giving you a homework problem, would it? ;)

Comment: @theorist According to him, the idea is that the reactor has a piston connected to a spring, so the force by the spring and pressure increases as the volume increases.

Comment: OK, that explanation helps.  I think the problem, as written, is presenting an underdetermined system.  I say this because if you can get the equilibrium state purely from the info. given, it means the equilibrium state is independent of the compounds reacting, which wouldn't make sense.  I.e., if you could calculate an equilibrium purely from the info. given above, that equilibrium would be the same for any reaction of the form $\ce{AB_3(g) -> AB_2(g) +1/2 B_2(g)}$, which, again, doesn't make sense. So what's missing is information specific to the chemical species involved.

Comment: @theorist Right, I guess I should've been more clear when I stated that all reference material with formation enthalpies/energies was available. I'll edit that into the question

Comment: If you have Kp at 1100 K, then you could combine that with your initial conditions to get advancement as a function of pressure.  I haven't tried it myself, but I think that would be your third indepedent equation.

Comment: @theorist Right, once we have Kp the problem is not hard to solve, so the main difficulty is in finding Kp. Unfortunately, the relation between gibbs energy change and Kp is not valid in our reactor setup here since the pressure is not constant.